# Large HDMI cable. Solid versus RJ45 Extensor

Tags: audio, hdmi, video

I need a 30 meters long HDMI cable. I've found solid cables that achieve this measure, and also found RJ45 adapters to extend short cables:

[image]                                         
[image]

**Is there any disadvantage in terms of video/audio quality, in using the RJ45 extensor?**

It is much cheaper, and in case it suffers any damage it would be much easier and cheap to replace it, so I have great interest in using it.

Comment: I haven't voted, but it appears that you are not asking for a recommendation, but rather about the downsides to a piece of hardware. If you edit your question to ask for a recommendation with a set of requirements, you would get a +1 from me.

Comment: @Cfinley I think this kind of question would fit nicely because it will directly lead to a product recommendation. However it does need some clarity as you said.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Unitek Y-5115 with 15m cables for 2 years now and it just works. I suspect that the 2*ethernet cable extenders simply use analog amplification of a digital signal (number of pairs in 2 ethernet cables > number of pairs in HDMI cable), so even other format still pass (eg DVI, I've tried) and no loss of quality is possible (until eventually digital connection breaks down).

Mind you that there are now extenders which use only 1 ethernet cable so they must work in a different way - I am NOT talking about them.

(BTW, the cable you mean is not really RJ45 and a real RJ45 plug wouldn't even fit the socket.)